# How do I create the str_shuffle from php in python

Tags: php, python, arrays

> Note I don't want to use pythons shuffle as that uses the Fisher-Yates
>   Shuffle algorithm I want to get the same result on both php and
>   python when the seed (random.seed/srand) is the same

My current code is:

```
def PHP_shuffle(string):
    array = list(string)
    shuffled_array = []
    arr_length = len(array)

    if(arr_length < 2):
        return array

    while(arr_length):
        rand_key = array_keys(array[randint(0, arr_length)]
        shuffled_array[rand_key] = array[rand_key]
        del array[rand_key]
    return shuffled_array
```

It does not work because array_keys is not in python I think I need to port it somehow.

Comment: Setting aside the problem of `array_keys`, have you verified that `randint` returns the same number in both Python and php, provided they have the same seed? It's probably worth double-checking that assumption before you build anything on top of it.

Comment: Python used the Mersenne Twister algorithm for `randint`. Luckily, it is also available on PHP, using `mt_rand()` instead of rand(). This should at least give you the same 'random' values for a given seed !

Comment: In Python 3, [`seed`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.seed) takes a version string, and on my machine running Python 3.6.0, `import random; random.seed('31337', version=1); print(random.randint(1,10))` prints 2.